# Not getting crash, It is going to dead state

Tags: android, logcat, crash-reports

In my application, if the application will crash, not getting any crash in device and I am not able to get crash report in logcat, Instead it is going to dead state. I tried with all scenarios **Verbose, Error, Debug** , but not getting crash in logcat. I don't know what is the issue here. I checked with sample application it will crash and getting crash report in logcat also.

Check the screen shot attached.

[image]

Because of that issue, it is very difficult to find the issue in which line the error coming.

So please help on this.

Thanks In Advance..

Comment: uncomment `super.onCreate`

Comment: Yes it will work, if I uncomment, But in other scenario if the app will crash not getting crash and not display logcat, So for that I am checking with comment that line. Here my question is why not getting crash, instead it is going to dead state.